# Can't call bsoncxx::document::value::view()

Tags: mongodb, c++11

I'd like to look at the results of retrieving a single document from a MongoDB using the C++ 3.0 driver. The [driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1value.html) describes the [view() method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1value.html#a453df78356c8bc55ed3bb455b242e853) of the [bsoncxx::document::value](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1value.html) class (which is returned by [mongocxx::collection::find_one](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#ab97f38c73a210477e0e901acc83de866)). When I attempt to use it like this:

```
#include <bsoncxx/document/view.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/document/value.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance>
#include <mongocxx/client>

mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::client conn{};
bsoncxx::document::view doc;

auto db = conn["test"];

try {
    auto docObj = db["collection"].find_one(document{} <<
        "field" << "value" << finalize);
    doc = docObj.view();
} catch (mongocxx::exception::query e) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't retrieve document";
    return NULL;
}

...
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
error: 'struct core::v1::optional<bsoncxx::v0::document::value>' has no member named 'view'
```

at the line

```
doc = docObj.view();
```

What am I doing wrong? If this is not the the correct idiom for using `find_one()`, what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 4):

Found it. The bsoncxx::optional template means that the members of bsoncxx::document::value are available as var->member. The above code should have read:

```
doc = docObj->view();
```

It was confusing because docObj is an object, not a pointer, but an object that presents its underlying object as though it were a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

`core::v1::optional<T>` acts much like `std::experimental::optional<T>`.
And as described in documentation for [std::experimental::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) (or, since c++17, [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)),

> When an object of type optional is [contextually converted to bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), the conversion returns true if the object contains a value and false if it does not contain a value.

you have to check your docObj for containing a value by applying operator bool to it because

> The behavior [of operator*] is undefined if *this does not contain a value

(there is described some bad_optional_access exception, but documentation for `operator*` says that trying to access contained value when there is no value leads to UB)

So, your code has to look like

```
if(docObj) {
    doc docObj->view();
} else {
    //Throw an exception? log an error to console?
    //Do nothing?
    std::cerr << "find_one() failed for" << std::endl << 
        bsoncxx::to_json(
                document{} << "field" << "value" << finalize
            ) << std::endl;
}
```

This may help if `find_one()` failed for some reason.

Yes, implementations of `core::v1::optional<T>` and `std::optional` may differ (at least I can't find it at [official api documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/annotated.html)). 
But it's better to check.

**UPD:** As shown in [file for stdx::optional](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/stdx/optional.hpp), I'm (partially?) right: it can use std::experimental::optional

Comment: -1 I have no idea what you're trying to say here.  Please remove your line about not being able to comment and flush this out into a full answer, explaining what you are trying to address.  As it stands, I think you're trying to point out an issue with the code that doesn't fully exist (is handled by a try catch block).